# Error when refactoring Tikz, scope argument gives error when given via a command

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, tikz-styles

When I do

```
    \begin{scope}[every node/.style={minimum size=1cm,draw,rectangle}]
        \node (v1) at (2,0) {$\#1 \cdot \#2$};
    \end{scope}
```

it works.

But when I do

```
   \newcommand{\operatorNode}{every node/.style={minimumcsize=1cm,draw,rectangle}}

    \begin{scope}[\operatorNode]
        \node (v1) at (2,0) {$\#1 \cdot \#2$};
    \end{scope}
```

I get the error:
Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/every node/.style={minimum size=1cm,draw,rectangle}' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

I think there is something strange going on in the internals. I'm working in Overleaf.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a new style with :`\tikzset{
    operatorNode/.style={
    every node/.style={minimum size=1cm,draw,rectangle}
    }
    }`

**An example:**

```
\documentclass[border= 0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

%\newcommand{\operatorNode}{every node/.style={minimumcsize=1cm,draw,rectangle}}

\tikzset{
operatorNode/.style={
every node/.style={minimum size=1cm,draw,rectangle}
}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[operatorNode]
        \node (v1) at (2,0) {$\#1 \cdot \#2$};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```